# How to restore an entire directory with gsutil rsync, while excluding old deleted files?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, rsync, gsutil

rsync -d option deletes extra files under dst_url not found under src_url.

If -d option is not used, and the source directory is destroyed, restored data will include old deleted files.
If -d option is used and a user wants to retrieve an old deleted a file, there is no way to restore it from GCS.

Is there a way that gsutil rsync can restore an entire directory, excluding old deleted files?
And at other times, restore an old deleted file?

There are two different ways [Samba rsync](https://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) can do this:

## 1 rsync --link-dest.

Each rsync is to a new empty time stamped dir.
Files that have not changed are hard linked from the previous run.
The result is many time stamps complete trees that can be restored as was at the time of the run.

To restore entire directory, copy the latest backup (old deleted files are not copied).
To restore a deleted file, copy a file from the latest backup that contains the file.

## 2 rsync --backup-dir.

Each file that would be replaced or deleted is instead moved into the backup directory.

To restore entire directory, copy the latest backup (old deleted files are not copied).
To restore a deleted file, copy a file from the backup directory.